# how to put checkboxes in datagrid in windows mobile 6 using c#?

Tags: windows-mobile, c#-3.0

how to put checkboxes in datagrid in windows mobile 6 using c#?

dataset dsAgent=table;
 DataTable dataTable = dsAgent.Tables[0];

```
            DataGridTableStyle tableStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();

            tableStyle.MappingName = dataTable.TableName;

            GridColumnStylesCollection columnStyles = tableStyle.GridColumnStyles;

            DataGridTextBoxColumn columnStyle = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
            columnStyle.MappingName = "FirstName";
            columnStyle.HeaderText = "Name";
            columnStyle.Width = 80;
            columnStyles.Add(columnStyle);

            //columnStyle = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
            //columnStyle.MappingName = "EmailAddress";
            //columnStyle.HeaderText = "EmailID";
            //columnStyle.Width = 150;
            //columnStyles.Add(columnStyle);

            columnStyle = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
            columnStyle.MappingName = "WorkPhone";
            columnStyle.HeaderText = "PhoneNo";
            columnStyle.Width = 150;
            columnStyles.Add(columnStyle);


            GridTableStylesCollection tableStyles = DataGrid.TableStyles;
            tableStyles.Add(tableStyle);


            DataGrid.PreferredRowHeight = 16;
            DataGrid.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            DataGrid.DataSource = dataTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code from and old blog by Eric Hartwell (pulled into SO using [the wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20120905035212/http://www.ehartwell.com/InfoDabble/DataGrid_extensions_for_the_Compact_Framework)):

```
    private void SetupTableStyles()
    {
       Color alternatingColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;
       DataTable vehicle = dataSource.Tables[1];

       // ID Column 
       DataGridCustomTextBoxColumn dataGridCustomColumn0 = new DataGridCustomTextBoxColumn();
       dataGridCustomColumn0.Owner = this.dataGrid1;
       dataGridCustomColumn0.Format = "0##";
       dataGridCustomColumn0.FormatInfo = null;
       dataGridCustomColumn0.HeaderText = vehicle.Columns[0].ColumnName;
       dataGridCustomColumn0.MappingName = vehicle.Columns[0].ColumnName;
       dataGridCustomColumn0.Width = dataGrid1.Width * 10 / 100;    // 10% of grid size
       dataGridCustomColumn0.AlternatingBackColor = alternatingColor;
       dataGridCustomColumn0.ReadOnly = true;
       dataGridTableStyle1.GridColumnStyles.Add(dataGridCustomColumn0);

       // Make column
       DataGridCustomTextBoxColumn dataGridCustomColumn1 = new DataGridCustomTextBoxColumn();
       dataGridCustomColumn1.Owner = this.dataGrid1;
       dataGridCustomColumn1.HeaderText = vehicle.Columns[1].ColumnName;
       dataGridCustomColumn1.MappingName = vehicle.Columns[1].ColumnName;
       dataGridCustomColumn1.NullText = "-Probably Ford-";
       dataGridCustomColumn1.Width = dataGrid1.Width * 40 / 100;     // 40% of grid size
       dataGridCustomColumn1.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
       dataGridCustomColumn1.AlternatingBackColor = alternatingColor;
       dataGridTableStyle1.GridColumnStyles.Add(dataGridCustomColumn1);

       // Mileage column
       DataGridCustomUpDownColumn dataGridCustomColumn2 = new DataGridCustomUpDownColumn();
       dataGridCustomColumn2.Owner = this.dataGrid1;
       dataGridCustomColumn2.HeaderText = vehicle.Columns[2].ColumnName;
       dataGridCustomColumn2.MappingName = vehicle.Columns[2].ColumnName;
       dataGridCustomColumn2.NullText = "-Unknown-";
       dataGridCustomColumn2.Width = dataGrid1.Width * 20 / 100;     // 20% of grid size
       dataGridCustomColumn2.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
       dataGridCustomColumn2.AlternatingBackColor = alternatingColor;
       dataGridTableStyle1.GridColumnStyles.Add(dataGridCustomColumn2);

       // Availability column 
       DataGridCustomCheckBoxColumn dataGridCustomColumn3 = new DataGridCustomCheckBoxColumn();
       dataGridCustomColumn3.Owner = this.dataGrid1;
       dataGridCustomColumn3.HeaderText = vehicle.Columns[3].ColumnName;
       dataGridCustomColumn3.MappingName = vehicle.Columns[3].ColumnName;
       dataGridCustomColumn3.NullText = "-Unknown-";
       dataGridCustomColumn3.Width = dataGrid1.Width * 10 / 100;     // 10% of grid size
       dataGridCustomColumn3.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
       dataGridCustomColumn3.AlternatingBackColor = alternatingColor;
       dataGridTableStyle1.GridColumnStyles.Add(dataGridCustomColumn3);

       // Fuel Level column
       DataGridCustomComboBoxColumn dataGridCustomColumn4 = new DataGridCustomComboBoxColumn();
       dataGridCustomColumn4.Owner = this.dataGrid1;
       dataGridCustomColumn4.HeaderText = vehicle.Columns[4].ColumnName;
       dataGridCustomColumn4.MappingName = vehicle.Columns[4].ColumnName;
       dataGridCustomColumn4.NullText = "-Unknown-";
       dataGridCustomColumn4.Width = dataGrid1.Width * 30 / 100;     // 30% of grid size
       dataGridCustomColumn4.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
       dataGridCustomColumn4.AlternatingBackColor = alternatingColor;
       dataGridTableStyle1.GridColumnStyles.Add(dataGridCustomColumn4);

       // Last Used column
       DataGridCustomDateTimePickerColumn dataGridCustomColumn5 = new DataGridCustomDateTimePickerColumn();
       dataGridCustomColumn5.Owner = this.dataGrid1;
       dataGridCustomColumn5.HeaderText = vehicle.Columns[5].ColumnName;
       dataGridCustomColumn5.MappingName = vehicle.Columns[5].ColumnName;
       dataGridCustomColumn5.NullText = "-Unknown-";
       dataGridCustomColumn5.Width = dataGrid1.Width * 30 / 100;     // 30% of grid size
       dataGridCustomColumn5.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
       dataGridCustomColumn5.AlternatingBackColor = alternatingColor;
       dataGridTableStyle1.GridColumnStyles.Add(dataGridCustomColumn5);

       // Grid, mapping
       dataGridTableStyle1.MappingName = vehicle.TableName;                       // Setup table mapping name
       dataGrid1.DataSource = vehicle;                                  

       // Setup grid's data source
       ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)dataGridCustomColumn4.HostedControl;
       DataTable fuel = dataSource.Tables[0];                                                    // Set up data source
       cb.DataSource = fuel;                                            

       // For combo box column
       cb.DisplayMember = fuel.Columns[0].ColumnName;
       cb.ValueMember = fuel.Columns[0].ColumnName;

       dataGrid1.CurrentRowIndex = 50;                                                            // Move to the middle of the table
    }
```

Comment: What's difficult about it?  It shows exactly what you're after.  If there is some part that is confusing or unclear, let us know and we can try to help clarify.  Post the code you've tried (what you have above has nothing about checkboxes at all) and maybe we can help steer you.

Answer (score 0):

For better checkbox UI look and feel, rather than big cross

```
private void DrawCheckBox(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, CheckState state)
        {
            int size;
            int boxTop;

            size = bounds.Size.Height < bounds.Size.Width ? bounds.Size.Height : bounds.Size.Width;
            size = size > ((int)g.DpiX / 7) ? ((int)g.DpiX / 7) : size;

            boxTop = bounds.Y + (bounds.Height - size) / 2;
            size = 12; // 13, so I made it 12
            boxTop = boxTop - 1;
            using (Pen p = new Pen(this.Owner.ForeColor))
            {
                g.DrawRectangle(p, bounds.X, boxTop, size, size);
            }

            if (state != CheckState.Unchecked)
            {
                using (Pen p = new Pen(state == CheckState.Indeterminate ? SystemColors.GrayText : SystemColors.ControlText))
                {
                    p.Width = 2;
                    int offset = 2;
                    int edgeOffset = 2;
                    g.DrawLine(p, bounds.X + offset, boxTop + offset + 2, bounds.X + (size / 2) - edgeOffset, boxTop + (size / 2) + edgeOffset);
                    g.DrawLine(p, bounds.X + (size / 2) - edgeOffset, boxTop + (size / 2) + edgeOffset, bounds.X + size - offset, boxTop + offset);
                }
            }
        }
```