# how to give checkbox options in datagrid in windows mobile? is it possible or not?

Tags: c#, datagrid, windows-mobile, compact-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to put checkboxes in datagrid in windows mobile 6 using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438346/how-to-put-checkboxes-in-datagrid-in-windows-mobile-6-using-c)

How can I give checkbox options in a datagrid in windows mobile. Is it possible or not?

Please help me.

Comment: So that's simple ... just use an implementation of [DataGridCustomColunmns](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netcfteam/archive/2006/04/25/583542.aspx), [see this article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29021/Grid-Control-for-NET-Compact-Framework)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ListView and set the CheckBoxes property to true.