# How to add Check Box to Data Grid in Windows mobile 6.0?

Tags: windows-mobile

Can U Please tell me How to add the Check Box  Column to Data Grid in Windows Mobile 6.0.

Give some Samples on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably best off checking out the custom data grid project that Ilya Tumanov created.  A full demo project is available for download from the following blog if you need the source code.

[MSDN Blog - Custom Data Grid](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netcfteam/archive/2006/04/25/583542.aspx)

[Direct link to the msi package](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-00-58-35-42/CustomDataGridSample.msi-)

You could also check...

[Possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438346/how-to-put-checkboxes-in-datagrid-in-windows-mobile-6-using-c)