# Customizing the DataGrid in Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, datagrid, compact-framework

I have a requirement to develop a CF (Windows Mobile 5) project for an old ScanGun (MC9090). I would like to add a few CheckBox columns and a Combobox column to optimize the small UI space. I found a reference to Eric Hartwell's DataGrid Extension ([how to put checkboxes in datagrid in windows mobile 6 using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438346/how-to-put-checkboxes-in-datagrid-in-windows-mobile-6-using-c)), and though the example code still exists, the link to the extension download is dead. I know the reference AND the technology are old, but I sure could use this to cut development time. I am hoping someone might have any ideas and/or still have a copy of the extension they would be willing to share. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the link to the download using the internet wayback machine, and (surprisingly) the link still is valid.  [Here it is](http://www.ehartwell.com/infodabble/images/f/f9/DataGrid.zip).  It's too large of a code base to simply post here, so I'm not sure what to do with it in the event the link ever dies.