# how to hide the first column in DataGrid or set text in the first column using .net comapct framework?

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, compact-framework

guys!
Here I want to hide the first column of DataGrid control using .NET Compact Framework 2013. The area that I want to hide is shown as below:
[DataGrid Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSUcC.png)

Or we can find another way, that is to display text in the first column of DataGrid that has been pointed out in red rectangle area as shown in picture above.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try with RowHeadersVisible=false? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438346/how-to-put-checkboxes-in-datagrid-in-windows-mobile-6-using-c where the "first column" (the RowHeader) is replaced by a checkbox for the row.

Comment: And so we can not fill in the RowHeaders with text while using .net compact framework, right?

Comment: You may try a custom paint of the lines or add a column to the table with the row header value(s)

Comment: Have you considered using a ListView instead?  It lacks that column you are trying to get rid of.